# Slice a pandas dataframe by index in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a pandas datafra `df` and I have the columns `A,B,C`.

I want to take the index' `idx=[1,10,12,17]` from column `B` - how is that done?

I have tried `df[idx,"B"], df.iloc[idx,"B"], df.loc[idx,"B"]`

Comment: I think `df.loc[idx,"B"]` is nice solution

Answer (score 2):

You can you `.loc` or `.iloc`.

```
idx = [1,10,12,17]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df.loc[idx, 'B']
df.iloc[idx, 1]
```

Result:

```
1     0.532895
10    0.197801
12    0.978466
17    0.847575
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: For some reason `df.loc[idx,"B"]` did not work before, but now it does. Thanks :)